# jQuery Not selector causes infinite loop

Tags: jquery, selector

The following code causes my browsers to crash. For Firefox, i've been given an option whether or not i want to stop jQuery because it was running longer than it should be.

```
div id="divLeaving">
    You are about to leave to: <span id="spanLeavingURL"></span>
    <a id="divLeavingYes" href="#">Yes</a><a id="divLeavingNo" href="#">No</a>
</div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a:not(#divLeavingYes, #divLeavingNo)").click(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            var test_if_local = url.indexOf("mycompany.com");
            if (test_if_local == -1) {
                $("#spanLeavingURL").text(url);
                $("#divLeavingYes").attr("href", url);
                $("#divLeavingNo").click(function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); });
                $("#divLeaving").dialog({ modal: true });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, if i remove the not selector it doesn't crash my browser.

```
<div id="divLeaving">
    You are about to leave to: <span id="spanLeavingURL"></span>
    <a id="divLeavingYes" href="#">Yes</a><a id="divLeavingNo" href="#">No</a>
</div>
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            var test_if_local = url.indexOf("mycompany.com");
            if (test_if_local == -1) {
                $("#spanLeavingURL").text(url);
                $("#divLeavingYes").attr("href", url);
                $("#divLeavingNo").click(function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); });
                $("#divLeaving").dialog({ modal: true });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do i change thes query so it selects all  except for #divLeavingYes and #divLeavingNo?

Comment: The code above doesn't crash Firefox for me. Is there any more code you can include?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about jQuery's implementation, but:

```
a:not(#divLeavingYes, #divLeavingNo)
```

is not a valid CSS3 Selector. The :not selector can only take a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation). Try:

```
a:not(#divLeavingYes):not(#divLeavingNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this, I include "event.stopPropagation();":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:not(#divLeavingYes, #divLeavingNo)").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var test_if_local = url.indexOf("mycompany.com");
        if (test_if_local == -1) {
            $("#spanLeavingURL").text(url);
            $("#divLeavingYes").attr("href", url);
            $("#divLeavingNo").click(function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); });
            $("#divLeaving").dialog({ modal: true });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not know what your browser, this example I worked perfectly in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safary. 
Before down, you could be more specific on which is your browser, or ask which browsers try this example. And you have to keep in mind that these scripts will not be perfect, and I have the full HTML to see if the error is in some other part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your HTML is structured, but perhaps you could get jQuery's slice() filter to do the trick...

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice